# How can I update my Github Actions CI script to install sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, cli, force-cli, sfdx-error

I used to have a script

```
      wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz
      mkdir sfdx-cli
      tar xJf sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz -C sfdx-cli --strip-components 1
      ./sfdx-cli/install
      sfdx update
```

in my github actions to install sfdx cli before any other steps or actions, it was broken today and stopped working.

When I tried to update the script to the following version

```
wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx/channels/stable/sfdx-linux-x64.tar.xz
mkdir ~/sfdx
tar xJf sfdx-linux-x64.tar.xz -C ~/sfdx --strip-components 1
export PATH=~/sfdx/bin:$PATH
sfdx update
```

it still doesn't work because the calling sfdx from the other steps produces an error

```
line 1: sfdx: command not found
```

Is there a fix or workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an easy solution for this:

```
node --version
npm install sfdx-cli --global
```

looks like node is already installed in Github Actions servers.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to leverage the official SFDX Docker image in your GitHub Action as well.

Here is my sample GitHub Action file:

https://github.com/banderson5144/funcondemo/blob/master/.github/workflows/sfdxvalidate.yml#L18

And here is the link to the official SFDX Docker Image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/salesforce/salesforcedx

Comment: this is really interesting option, however, when I try to use it, the following preexisting command now fails:

limits=$(sfdx force:limits:api:display -u devhub | awk '$1 ~ /ScratchOrg/ { print }')

limits=$(sfdx force:limits:api:display -u devhub | awk '$1 ~ /ScratchOrg/ { print }')
  echo $limits  
  limits="${limits//'%'/'%25'}"
  limits="${limits//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
  limits="${limits//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
  echo  "::set-output name=limits::$limits"
: Bad substitution

Comment: for some strange reason some commands like git rev-parse HEAD 
started failing with 128
and I don't understand why
This started after switching to docker image

Comment: SFDX docker image has obsolete git version 2.17.1